Which brain structures are most involved in the construction of the motion image in motor imagery?
I have several possible answers. They are motor cortex, somatosensory (sensorimotor) cortex, cerebellum, insular cortex, premotor cortex, cingulate gyrus, occipital cortex and temporal cortex.
Obviously, the motor and premotor cortex are suitable. But then... the cerebellum is involved in motor movements, but I am not sure that it is used in the construction of images, because it is a separate part of the brain, which is responsible for execution, and not for representation
Probably somatosensory cortex is used to represent tastes and tactile sensations
I found an article about the participation of the insular cortex in this process, but perhaps it is not used much - https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/
The cingulate gyrus is definitely not there, it has other functions
The occipital cortex of the brain is used for the primary processing of visual information. Although he is not involved in the construction of images, perhaps this is the right answer. For example, athletes can imagine how they would run an obstacle course, they see themselves from the outside, they see how they jump, run. The occipital cortex is most likely involved
The auditory cortex is needed to represent sounds, it is part of the temporal cortex
This was the information that I could find in open sources. Perhaps it will be useful

The correct answer is motor cortex, premotor cortex, somatosensory (sensorimotor) cortex and cerebellum
